# Look-and-feel of an applet window changes on subsequent displays

Tags: java, applet, look-and-feel

I have an applet that displays a dialog box on click of a button.  When the dialog box is first displayed, it is shown using the native look-and-feel of the OS.  When the dialog box is displayed a second time (same page, browser, OS, etc.), it is shown using what I think is the Swing look-and-feel.  To my knowledege, I do not explicity set the look-and-feel of my applet.  Should I be doing so to avoid this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: I had some possible related behaviour. The font size on labels would become bigger on second display. Unfortunately, I never got to the bottom of that, but I think it was something to do with using UIManager.put().

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate what you mean by "display". A different screen on the same computer? A different computer? Is the same version of Java installed? Is the exact same version of the OS installed?

The user can influence the L&F with environment variables. [These docs may help](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

Also, for the native Windows XP L&F, [you need a special DLL](https://winlaf.dev.java.net/).